# Area A & slope M of the region enclosed by the cardioid?

Tags: calculus

I would like to get a better understanding of this problem and what it could be?

“Find the area $ A$ of the region enclosed by the cardioid $ R = 1 - \cos\theta$ and the Slope $ M$ of the tangent line $ \theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$”

Comment: What have you tired? what do you know about how to get area of a closed curve?